# Using df.to_sql to insert last names with apostrophes

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

Trying to upload a dataframe to Postgres. One of the columns is "last_name" and includes last names with apostrophes.

I've tried replacing the apostrophe in the dataframe with a double apostrophe, but it doesn't seem to take. See code below:

`df2['last_name'] = df2['last_name'].replace({'\'': '\'\''}, regex=True)`

Here is the error code I get in return (user personal info removed:

```
  File "rooftop_active-pending.py", line 182, in <module>
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(eval(result), columns=['serial_number','reg_status','full_name','email','first_name','last_name', 'phone_number'])
  File "<string>", line 1
    [('ESDENM-004B926267','pending','DENNIS O&#x27;HARA','dennisjohara@xxxxxxx.xxx','DENNIS','O'HARA','None')]
                                                                                                   ^
```

I'm using this line to insert the dataframe into the postrgres table:

`users.to_sql('reg_status', engine, index=False, if_exists='append',method=multi)`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you try to `INSERT VALUES` that record into your database? this *may* be more of a database limitation rather than a pandas error. Also - what engine are you using? `SQLAlchemy`? `pyodbc`? other?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using SQLAlchemy. I use this method with other scripts without error, but this is the first time I've run into this issue.

Comment: are you sure you're adding double apostraphies ? I had a similair problems and I had to escape apostraphe with a double quotation mark.